# syntax error in python function definitions

Tags: python, function, syntax-error

sorry if I sound like a complete idiot when asking this, I'm very new to Python. When I create a function like this :

```
def load_content(name, colorkey=None, datatype):
```

It tells me there is a syntax error. From what I can tell, this is the right way to write a function. Like I said, I'm very new. Does anyone know what's wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You can't have default arguments between non-default arguments

```
def load_content(name, colorkey=None, datatype=None):
```

or

```
def load_content(name, datatype, colorkey=None):
```

Comment: Wow! You were incredibly fast! Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Default arguments must be at the end of the argument list, but before `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

Default parameter MUST be the last variable. So change to:

```
def load_content(name, datatype, colorkey=None):
...
```